# Twitter API cursor PHP

Tags: php, twitter, cursor

Already I have a script that collects the first 5000 users from friends/ids.
I want to collect all friends so I have to move through cursors to get them. I think I understand the way the cursor works but still I'm not able to make it work. I'm trying to acceed to next_cursor but don't know what I'm doing wrong.

It seems like the cursor I'm trying to get isn't properly called.

Would like some feedback with these because twitter's API doesn't give any real example.

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
session_start();
$user = $_POST['nombre'];
$_SESSION['user']=$_POST['nombre'];
$usuario = $user;


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "twitter";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
 'oauth_access_token' => "k1",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "k2",
'consumer_key' => "k3",
'consumer_secret' => "k4"

);

//https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=microsoft

$cursor = "cursor=".-1;
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json';
$getfield = '?'.$cursor.'screen_name='.$usuario;
$requestMethod = 'GET';


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$json = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(true, array(CURLOPT_CAINFO => dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem'));

$arrayFriends = json_decode($json, true,512,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);

echo 'Usuario' .";". 'Nombre'.";".'Location'.";".'Numero Amigos'.";".'Numero     followers'.";".'Descripcion'."\n";

foreach($arrayFriends['next_cursor'] as $curs){
foreach($arrayFriends['ids'] as $obj){
while($cursor != 0){
    //$cursor->$arrayFriends['ids']->next_cursor;
    $cursor = $curs;
    //$cursor = "&cursor=" + $cursor; 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO friends (user, id) VALUES ('$usuario','$obj')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        //echo "New record created successfully";
        header("Location:logic.php");
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
  }
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: hey guys, can someone give me a bit of feedback. I'm trying to solve this but loosing a lot of time on it.

Comment: yo guys, still isn't working and need an advice or something !

Comment: I am sharing the code for fetching all friends using cursor. However this is note a good practice to fetch all friends in one go. You will still crawl only 3000 friends as twitter allowing 15 request/15min window and max 200 results per request.  
Prefer to store next_cursor  in database and make new request by retrieving cursor value from database. You can use cron-job for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will fetch upto 3000 friends.

**Running time of the script is approx 3-5 minutes**

```
//function to fetch friends of the authenticating user

function getAllFriends($auth_user_screen_name)
{
    //---getting application tokens and connection to database
   $arraySettings = defaultSettings();

  $con = $arraySettings['connection'];

  //create api instance
   \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey('consumerKey', 'consumerSecret');
   $objTwitter = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();

   $oauth_token = "oauth_token";
   $oauth_token_secret = "oauth_token_secret";

   $objTwitter->setToken($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);

   //initialize empty array to store friends data returned from API     
   $friendsData=array();

  if (strlen($oauth_token) > 0 && strlen($oauth_token_secret) > 0) {

    $cursor = -1;
    $j=0;
    while ($cursor != 0)
    {
        $params = array(
            'screen_name' => $auth_user_screen_name,
            'count' => 200,
            'cursor' => $cursor
        );

        $json = $objTwitter->friends_list($params);
        $httpStatus = $json->httpstatus;

        $jsonFriends=(array)$json;

        //meta is user defined key 
        $friendsData['meta']['remaining']=$jsonFriends['rate']['remaining'];
        $friendsData['meta']['seconds_to_reset']=($jsonFriends['rate']['reset'] - time());

        if ($httpStatus == 200) {

            echo "remaining requests " . $jsonFriends['rate']['remaining'] . '<br>';
            echo "next reset after (sec) " . ($jsonFriends['rate']['reset'] - time()) . '<br>';

            $lenght = count($jsonFriends['users']);

            $cursor = $jsonFriends['next_cursor'];
            echo "next_cursor=>" . $cursor . "<br>";

            $i = 0;  //loop counter


            while ($i < $lenght) {

                $friendsData[$j]['screen_name']=$profileScreenName = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->screen_name;
                $friendsData[$j]['name']=$profileFullName = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->name;
                $friendsData[$j]['location']=$profileLocation = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->location;
                $friendsData[$j]['description']=$profileDescription = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->description;
                $friendsData[$j]['followers_count']=$followersCount = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->followers_count;
                $friendsData[$j]['friends_count']=$friendsCount = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->friends_count;

                $friendsData['']=$language = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->lang;
                $friendsData['']=$profileTwitterId = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->id;
                $friendsData['']=$isVerified = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->verified;
                $friendsData['']=$joinDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($jsonFriends['users'][$i]->created_at));
                $friendsData['']=$userWebsiteUrl = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->url;
                $friendsData['']=$tweetsCount = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->statuses_count;

                $friendsData['']=$defaultProfileImage = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->default_profile_image;

                $friendsData['']=$favouritesCount = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->favourites_count;
                $friendsData['']=$isGeoEnabled = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->geo_enabled;
                $friendsData['']=$utcOffset = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->utc_offset;
                $friendsData['']=$timeZone = $jsonFriends['users'][$i]->time_zone;


                $i++; //counter for friends in particular cursor
                $j++; //counter for friends for all friends including all cursor requests

            }

        } else {
               //if httpStatus other than 200
            $friendsData['meta']['error_code']=$errorCode = $jsonFriends['errors'][0]->code;
            $friendsData['meta']['error_message']=$errorMessage = $jsonFriends['errors'][0]->message;


            echo "<pre>";
            //print error and rate data
            print_r($friendsData['meta']); 


        }
        // check whether Api limit exceed
        if ($friendsData['meta']['remaining']==0)
        {

            echo "<br>please wait=>".$friendsData['meta']['seconds_to_reset']." seconds";
            break;
        }

    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($friendsData); //print all friends data including errors if any

  }
}


//call function to fetch all friends 
//only max 3000 friends will retrieved in single request
getAllFriends('myUsername');
```